# Auto self updating application installer with WIX?

Tags: wix, auto-update

I have standalone setup project created with wix. And I need some solution for auto update my application.My application should check for new version on start up and automatically download and install new version if available.What's the best solution to do this? Can anyone give me some examples?Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Burn as your bootstrapper/chainer (something I definitely recommend when distributing MSI files over the internet) then you can create a custom bootstrapper application that implements the update mechanism. This is how the WiX toolset updates itself. You can see the code in WiX v3.7 (or later) branch in `src\Setup\WixBA\UpdateViewModel.cs`.